# Bookmarks in django object got simplelazyobject when adding user instance Why

Tags: django, typeerror, addition, attributeerror, bookmarks

Have wasted alot of time researching and trying to figure out how to implement bookmarks in django. I tried CBV but i gave up. I tried fbv but I keep on getting this error:

```
TypeError at 'Bookmark' instance expected, got SimpleLazyObject: User: ****
```

Here is my View:

```
@login_required
def company_bookmark(request, slug):
    user = request.user
    model = get_object_or_404(Company, slug=slug)
    if user.is_authenticated:
        if model.bookmark.filter(id=user.id).exists():
            model.bookmark.remove(request.user)
        else:
            model.bookmark.add(request.user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(model.get_absolute_url())
    else:
        messages.warning(request, 'you must be authenticated first')
```

I wrap it in condition statement and still got same error, I added the condition in html to no avail

```html
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <a href="{% url 'company:bookmark' slug=company.slug %}"
       value="{{ company.slug }}" type="submit" class="btn_1 full-width outline wishlist">
      <i class="icon_heart"></i> Add to Favourite
    </a>
    {% endif %}
```

I even tried to add id to view like this

```
model.bookmark.remove(request.user.id)
```

it bring another error:

```
AttributeError at
'int' object has no attribute '_state'
```

Here is model

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120, help_text='Name of your company', )
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    bookmark = GenericRelation(Bookmark,  related_query_name='company_bookmark')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        slug = slugify(self.name)
        self.slug = slug
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('company:detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


class Bookmark(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

and Error

```
Traceback:

File "C:\Users\postgres\desktop\job\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\postgres\desktop\job\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\postgres\desktop\job\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\postgres\desktop\job\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\postgres\desktop\biz\src\bookmarks\views.py" in company_bookmark
  18.             model.bookmark.add(request.user)

File "C:\Users\postgres\desktop\job\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\fields.py" in add
  598.                     check_and_update_obj(obj)

File "C:\Users\postgres\desktop\job\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\contenttypes\fields.py" in check_and_update_obj
  585.                         self.model._meta.object_name, obj

Exception Type: TypeError at /company/inceptor-kenya/bookmark
Exception Value: 'Bookmark' instance expected, got <SimpleLazyObject: <User: Gracelynn>>
```

If I can get help I would be much grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share your models.py as well please? especially Company and Bookmark models.

Comment: Also, you really should add the full error stacktrace, so we can see where exactly the error comes from.

Comment: Did you clip the company model? I can't see any field named "slug"

Comment: and what is the reason you are using generic relations for this?

Comment: I just removed other fields, let me add them. I use generic relation since I want to use bookmark for other models. t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is raised because you need to add a `Bookmark` instance and not an `User` instance to `model.bookmark` (where `model` is a `Company` instance).

Your code:

```
if model.bookmark.filter(id=user.id).exists():
    model.bookmark.remove(request.user)
else:
    model.bookmark.add(request.user)
```

That could  be reworked to something like this, for example:

```
# search bookmarks of this 'Company' with this 'user'
bookmark = model.bookmark.filter(user=user).first()

if bookmark is not None:
    bookmark.delete()
else:
    bookmark = Bookmark()
    bookmark.user = request.user
    bookmark.content_object = model
    bookmark.save()
```

Comment: Thanks so much. You saved my life. You are right. I think the bookmark model (as opposed to if i had just added a many to many field in company model) is what was really needed. I could never figure this by myself. Thanks so much...